# Nginx is redirecting subdomain to main domain

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-config

I have two domains,

1. [zerp.io](https://zerp.io) (ssl installed)
2. [app.zerp.io](http://app.zerp.io) (only http)

in zerp.io (main domain) a wordpress website is hosted and is working fine. I am trying to deploy a React app on app.zerp.io using nginx. I deleted the default file and created new file app.zerp.io at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` I also created same file at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` and created a symlink between them. I checked the DNS entry, app.zerp.io and [www.app.zerp.io](http://www.app.zerp.io) is pointing to the public Ip of the correct server where React App resides.

Here's my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/app.zerp.io` file

```
server {
        listen 80;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name www.app.zerp.io app.zerp.io;
        location / {
                   proxy_pass localhost:3000;
                   proxy_ser_header host $host;
        }


}
```

The problem is, whenever I try to reach http://app.zerp.io through web browser it redirects me to https://zerp.io. Here's what I did so far,

1. I checked DNS using an online tool, its correctly pointing to the server
2. I did not use any 301 redirects in the configuration file as you can see above
3. when I try `curl app.zerp.io` from the production server (in Germany), sometimes it gives 200 with correct response and sometimes it gives 301 (moved permanently) crazy isn't it
4. When I try `curl app.zerp.io` from my local computer it always give me 301 although I do not have any 301 in my nginx config file
5. I thought, may be its a cache issue on my chrome, to my surprise no, I cleared the cache and hard reload, I even tried incognito mode with no success, it always redirect me to https://zerp.io
6. When I try `curl app.zerp.io` from my local computer using a VPS it correctly opens the website app.zerp.io.
7. I do not have any ssl certificate so there are not redirects from http to https in http://app.zerp.io

Its been two days, Its making me crazy, I am assuming it has something to do with DNS resolution. Can some please help me out

Comment: Can it have something to do with caching? When I go to the url app.zerp.io I am prompted for a username and password (title also is `React app`). zerp.io just shows me static pages (i.e. wordpress)

Comment: Try incognito or a completely different browser, or guest mode in chrome.

Comment: Does your secure domain issue [an HSTS header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security)? This could cause the browser to ignore your http subdomain.